# Can a virus downloaded in VirtualBox VM get transferred to the host computer

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virus, anti-virus

If I download a virus in VirtualBox VM then does it store that virus data in the host computer's file explorer infecting the host computer with the virtual one? If so, can any Anti-Virus like Quick Heal detect and delete the virus from both the type of computers.

Comment: Please remember that viruses are never safe to download. You shouldn't download viruses in any case. There is always a risk. I don't know what you are trying to do, but I hope you know what you are doing. Just a friendly reminder :)

Answer (score 2):

> If I download a virus in VirtualBox VM then does it store that virus data in the host computer's file explorer infecting the host computer with the virtual one?

For virtual machines installed on a virtual disk (VHD, VDI, VMDK etc):
This is possible only if there are shared folders between the virtual machine and the host. If the "Virus" is downloaded in a folder that is shared with the host, only then it can spread to the host machine.

If the virtual machine is installed on a physical disk, the risk of the virus affecting the host system's files is much greater.

> If so, can any Anti-Virus like Quick Heal detect and delete the virus from both the type of computers.

If there is an antivirus installed on the host system, it cannot scan inside of a virtual machine's files(if and only if the virtual machine is installed on a virtual hard disk) that are not being shared. Obviously, if there are shared folders, then files may get scanned and viruses may get deleted if they are detected.

Again, if the virtual machine is installed on a physical hard disk, then antivirus programs will be able to scan and remove any affected files.